# Get PCM byte array from MediaFoundationResampler, Naudio

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I'm working on a method to resample a wav file, here's the method:

```
internal byte[] ResampleWav(byte[] rawPcmData, int frequency, int bits, int channels, int newFrequency)
{
    byte[] pcmData;

    using (MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(rawPcmData))
    {
        RawSourceWaveStream Original = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(frequency, bits, channels));
        using (MediaFoundationResampler conversionStream = new MediaFoundationResampler(Original, new WaveFormat(newFrequency, bits, channels)))
        {
            // Here should go the code to get the array of bytes with the resampled PCM data
        }
    }

    return pcmData;
}
```

The problem here is that there isn't any property in the `MediaFoundationResampler` that returns the size of the buffer. The method should return an array of bytes with the resampled PCM data only.

Thanks in advance!

--Edit

After some time working, I could get this:

```
internal byte[] WavChangeFrequency(byte[] rawPcmData, int frequency, int bits, int channels, int newFrequency)
{
    byte[] pcmData;
    using (MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(rawPcmData))
    {
        RawSourceWaveStream Original = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(frequency, bits, channels));
        using (MediaFoundationResampler conversionStream = new MediaFoundationResampler(Original, newFrequency))
        {

            //Start reading PCM data
            using (MemoryStream wavData = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((conversionStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    wavData.Write(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                }
                pcmData = wavData.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return pcmData;
}
```

"Seems" to work fine, but there's another problem, seems that the PCM data byte array is greater than expected. Here's one of the tests I've tested with the method:

Input settings:

```
44100Hz
16 Bits
01 Channel 
1846324 Bytes of PCM data
```

Expected (when I resample the same wav file with Audition, Audacity and WaveFormatConversionStream I get this):

```
22050Hz
16 Bits
01 Channel 
923162 Bytes
```

MediaFoundationResampler result:

```
22050Hz
16 Bits
01 Channel 
923648 Bytes
```

And the size changes drastically if I change the size of the readBuffer array.

The main problem is that `MediaFoundationResampler` doesn't have the property `Length` to know the real size of the resampled PCM data buffer. Using `WaveFormatConversionStream` the code would be this, but the quality is not very good:

```
internal byte[] WavChangeFrequency(byte[] rawPcmData, int frequency, int bits, int channels, int newFrequency)
{
    byte[] pcmData;

    using (MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(rawPcmData))
    {
        RawSourceWaveStream Original = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(frequency, bits, channels));

        using (WaveFormatConversionStream wavResampler = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(newFrequency, bits, channels), Original))
        {
            pcmData = new byte[wavResampler.Length];
            wavResampler.Read(pcmData, 0, pcmData.Length);
        }
    }

    return pcmData;
}
```

What should I do to get the expected PCM data array, using the `MediaFoundationResampler`?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot calculate the new length using your method’s parameters frequency and newFrequency?

Comment: Well, probably yes, but I'm not sure about how to do it. What would the formula be?

Comment: If the only change is the sampling frequency, something like: var NewLength = rawPcmData.Length * (newFrequency / frequency); There will most probably be some length rounding issues. I don’t know this library, so this might be a bad way to solve your problem.

Comment: Tested it, but doesn't work, not sure why but gives zero. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Strange, I did a quick test and it seemed to work. I'll try again tonight when I'll have time.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

I'm not familiar with the NAudio Library, so there might be a more proper way of doing this.

**EDIT**

Still not a good answer, seems still off by a few bytes...
Some corrections to the code, using Mark Heath (NAudio creator) comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481756/9658671

I keep the answer here for now, as it might help for finding a real answer, but I'll edit or remove it if necessary.

**/EDIT**

The difference in length between the file produced by Audition and your code is 923648 - 923162 = 486 bytes, which is less than your 1024 buffer.

It can be explained by the following mechanism:

At the very last call to the `Read` method, the remaining byte count is inferior to your buffer size. So instead of getting 1024 bytes, you get less.

But your code still adds a full 1024 byte group, instead of a smaller number. That explains the 486 bytes difference and the fact that this number will change if you choose another buffer size.

Fixing this should be easy.

From NAudio documentation:
https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/fb35ce8367f30b8bc5ea84e7d2529e172cf4c381/Docs/WaveProviders.md

> **The Read method returns the number for bytes that were read**. This
> should never be more than numBytes and can only be less if the end of
> the audio stream is reached. NAudio playback devices will stop playing
> when Read returns 0.

So instead of pushing always 1024 bytes at each iteration, just push the number returned by the `Read` method.

Also, from Mark Heath comment:

> the buffer size should be configurable to be an exact multiple of the
> block align of the WaveStream

So instead of choosing a "random" buffer size, use a multiple of the block align.

```cs
internal byte[] WavChangeFrequency(byte[] rawPcmData, int frequency, int bits, int channels, int newFrequency, int BlockAlign)
{
    byte[] pcmData;
    var BufferSize = BlockAlign * 1024;
    using (MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(rawPcmData))
    {
        RawSourceWaveStream Original = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(frequency, bits, channels));
        using (MediaFoundationResampler conversionStream = new MediaFoundationResampler(Original, newFrequency))
        {

            //Start reading PCM data
            using (MemoryStream wavData = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var ByteCount = 0;
                var readBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                while ((ByteCount = conversionStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    wavData.Write(readBuffer, 0, ByteCount);
                }
                pcmData = wavData.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return pcmData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!, I've just test it, but sill happens, the array length is 923040 instead of 923162. :(