# Is there anyway to Read NAudio stream instead of writing it to file then read it again

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, stream, naudio

I have been using Naudio package to convert MP4 audio to WAV, so far things are working out but I have to save the WAV file after converting it

```cs
    // create media foundation reader to read the AAC encoded file from URL
    using (MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(audioUrl))
    // resample the file to PCM with same sample rate, channels and bits per sample
    using (ResamplerDmoStream resampledReader = new ResamplerDmoStream(reader,
        new WaveFormat(reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, 2)))

    // create WAVe file
    using (WaveFileWriter waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(fileFullPath, 
    resampledReader.WaveFormat))
    // save wav file physically on os
    resampledReader.CopyTo(waveWriter);
```

I tried to read waveWriter stream but apparently I can't do that as its write only stream
so my question is is there any way I can read waveWriter directly instead of saving it to a file then read that file again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write NAudio WaveStream to a Memory Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500222/how-to-write-naudio-wavestream-to-a-memory-stream)

Comment: yup, that seems to be what I am looking for thanks for linking it